# Alternate of populate in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array called `group` containing a list of IDs, I have the find and populate statement below which works perfectly with this and I use populate to get the additional data - query below:

```
var stories = await Story
  .find( { 'group' : { $in : group } } )
  .populate('group')
  .populate('createdBy')
  .sort('-created')
```

I have an aggregate query (below) which does what I want but 1) it does not use the values in the `group` array, it simply returns all of the content, and 2) I don't get the additional data for the `group` and `createdBy` fields as I do for the `find` above.

```
var spellings = await Spelling.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "keyStageLevel": 1, "spellingLevel": 1 } },
  { "$group" : {
    "_id": { "keyStageLevel": "$keyStageLevel", "class": "$class" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "spellingLevel": "$spellingLevel",
        "class": "$class",
        "name": "$name",
        "spellings": "$spellings",
        "created": "$created",
        "_id": "$_id",
        "group": "$group",
        "createdBy": "$createdBy"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Edit - here is an example spelling document:

```
 {
    "_id":"5b1ff6f62bb1894efcf76ea0",
    "spellings":["here","are","spellings"],
    "name":"withclass",
    "group":"5ab79a639083cf35339b880a",
    "createdBy":"5ab79185d47b833506ff94b1",
    "created":"2018-06-12T16:38:14.571Z",
 }
```

Can anyone help with how to use the values in the `group` array in my `aggregate` statement and how I can add in the additional data for the `group` and `createdBy` fields as I do for the `find` ?

Comment: you need to use  `$lookup` aggregation stage which easily populate your `group` and `createdBy`... which mongodb version do you have?

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, I'm on v 3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation to populate the `group` and the `createdBy` field

```
var spellings = await Spelling.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "group": { "$in": group }}},
  { "$sort": { "keyStageLevel": 1, "spellingLevel": 1 } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": CreatedBy.collection.name,
    "let": { "createdBy": "$createdBy" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$createdBy" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "createdBy"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Group.collection.name,
    "let": { "group": "$group" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$group" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "group"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$group" },
  { "$unwind": "$createdBy" },
  { "$group" : {
    "_id": { "keyStageLevel": "$keyStageLevel", "class": "$class" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "spellingLevel": "$spellingLevel",
        "class": "$class",
        "name": "$name",
        "spellings": "$spellings",
        "created": "$created",
        "_id": "$_id",
        "group": "$group",
        "createdBy": "$createdBy"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```